# Android Printing Font Error

Tags: java, android, printing, fonts

I create a application to print from slip printer. The output is good. But one thing, I used custom font(Zawgyi Font). This font is not show correctly and appear unknown words.

[image]

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                String printer_ip = list.get(i);
                Socket sock = new Socket(printer_ip, 9100);
                PrintWriter oStream = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
                //DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
               // DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(sb.toString()));
                oStream.println(sb.toString());
                oStream.close();
                sock.close();
        }
```

This is my printing code.

Comment: make it sans serif

Comment: @Eminem how bro ? any sample code ?